# The link between Satake parameter and Godement-Jacquet L-function of an automorphic representation of $GL_{n}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, l-functions, langlands-conjectures

**Origin of the question:** I'm reading the [following survey](https://math.ou.edu/%7Ekmartin/papers/shahidi-prep.pdf) of K. Martin, more generally I'm looking for the "best way" to define L-function associated to an automorphic representation of a reductive algebraic group $G$.

**Assumptions and notations:** I assume when I will consider general reductive group $G$ that there exists a Gelfand pair (G,K) so that according to [B. Gross](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Egross/preprints/sat.pdf) survey, the Satake isomorphism holds. In the following I will consider $\pi_{n}$ (resp. $\pi$) an automorphic representation of $Gl_{n}$ (resp. of $G$ a reductive group).

In the above survey of K. Martin, it is explained p.8 that local L-factor (for L-function of Godement and Jacquet) of $\pi_{2}$ at $p$ is a complex polynomial of $p^ {s}$ and $p^{-s}$ (defined by the zeta integral of a matrix coefficient of $\pi_{2}$).

**Question:**

1 Why/How is this polynomial linked to the polynomial associated to the Satake parameter of $\pi_{2}$? It is not clear for me since the first construction is analytic and the other is more algebraic..

2 According to the answer of this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44657/principal-l-functions-on-gln/44701?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C21.2301#44701) the Jacquet-Godement construction generalizes to $\pi_{n}$ so my question 1 is actually about $\pi_{n}$.

3 Even if I understand more or less the Satake isomorphism and its consequences (thanks to the really good survey of B.Gross that I shared above), I feel really uncomfortable with... Is there a philosophy behind the Satake isomorphism? (Maybe the historical goal of Satake isomorphism could enlight me)

4 Finally, at the beginning of this question I said that I was looking for the "best way" to associate an L-function to $\pi$. By that I mean the L-function for which we hope the Langlands correspondence hold. Does the construction of Jacquet and Godement generalizes to $\pi$? Is the Satake isomorphism the best way to obtain L-function (and why)?

Comment: When you say why/how is it linked, you mean how is the relationship between them proved, not what is the relationship, right?

Comment: Those notes weren't intended to give you a solid understanding of Godement-Jacquet, just an idea of what it's about.  You should read some of the other references mentioned there for what happens other groups (e.g., Cogdell's notes).  For 1, did you understand the unramified calculation?

Comment: Yes @WillSawin it is exactly that.